# Keeping leading zeros in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro

Tags: javascript, acrobat

How do I retain a 0 in the numeric formatted fields when the zero is at the beginning of a number? right now the field drops the 0 and proceeds to display the second number.
For example, in the number field, if i enter "00100", then it displays as "100".

I have written a keystroke script to accept only numbers but I need to limit the numbers to 6 digits

Please help.

```
function numOnly_ks() {

    // Get all of the characters that have been entered in to the field
    var value = AFMergeChange(event);

    // Do nothing if field is blank
    if(!value) return;

    // Reject the entry if the entry doesn't match the regular expression
    if(!AFExactMatch(/^[0-9 /+]+$/, value)) event.rc = false;

}
```

Comment: `var leadingZeros = ('00000' + value).substr(-6);`

Comment: @Teemu How should I use this? Is it keystroke script? Please help. I'm a begginer

Comment: How would I know, you haven't provided any code where to use it. Just use it anywhere you need a six-digit _string_ with leading zeros. JavaScript numbers don't have leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to add this to the Validate event:

```
event.value = util.printf("%,106d", event.value) ;
```

Note: I have not tested it, but it should work. You might have a look at the util.printf() method description in the Acrobat JavaScript documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need the field entry to be a numerical value (i.e., do you need to use the value for mathematical purposes)?  If not, you can just set the field to be a text entry, which will allow a user to enter numbers as text in the field, and will thus allow the entry of leading zeros.  To do this, go to the following menu: Edit>Edit Text & Images>Forms>Edit>[then click on the field you want to edit]>Edit Fields>Show Field Properties>Format>[then set "Select Field Properties" to "None"].  This change will allow a user to enter any characters in the field, so it's not going to be an option for any form owner/creator who needs to limit the field entry parameters/rules for users.  But it works as a quick one-off solution to force leading zeros.